# Casting literals to PChar / PAnsiChar

Tags: delphi, access-violation, c-strings

I've got really stupid question...
Why this code:

```
PChar('x');
```

causes "Access violation" error?
Compiler optimalisation?

Example:

```
var s: String;
...
s := StrPas(PAnsiChar('x'));
```

This causes AV in Delphi 5 / Delphi XE

Or this one:

```
Windows.MessageBox(0, PChar('x'), PChar('y'), 0);
```

This causes AV in Delphi 5, but not in Delphi XE
In XE there is an empty MessageBox

Console example:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils, Windows;
var s: String;
begin
  s := StrPas(PChar('xxx'));   // EAccessViolation here
end.
```

Comment: Another really stupid question: what version of Delphi are you using? And how can anybody reproduce this? Because just that line alone won't compile.

Comment: Corrected + examples

I needed to change string variable to literals for testing and I was a bit suprised...

@David Heffernan That's a point xD

Comment: I wonder. Is `'x'` a char literal? And so only a single character? Perhaps that's what I am missing.

Comment: @David Indeed... Just tested, just `x` raises an AV, and `xx` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StrPas(PAnsiChar('x'));
```

I posit that `'x'` is treated as a character literal rather than a string literal. And so the cast is not valid. If so then this will work as you would expect

```
StrPas('x');
```

due to an implicit conversion. Or

```
StrPas(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('x')));
```

thanks to the explicit conversion.

I think the former is probably to be preferred. Literals don't need casting to null terminated pointer types. The compiler can emit the correct code without the cast. And casts always run the risk of suppressing an error.

Comment: Ooook... You are right. Thanks for explanation! :)

I added literal for testing piece of code and then I was a bit susprised...

Comment: Delphi is a bit lame here. All stemming from the use of the same delimiter for strings and characters.

Comment: In older versions, `PAnsiChar('x')` did indeed cast a single character as-is into a pointer.  That behavior was changed in 10.4 to make a single-character cast return a null-terminated string instead.